# How to get user group using TFS API in asp.net MVC

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tfs

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/12/07/tfs-api-part-41-manage-groups-and-members.aspx

He can't get group name belong to a user using WPF base on TeamProjectPicker instant:

```
private void BtnConnectClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisableUi();
        var tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.NoProject, false);
        tpp.ShowDialog();
        if (tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection == null) return;

        EnableUi();

        _tfs = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
        _css = (ICommonStructureService)_tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
        _gss = (IGroupSecurityService)_tfs.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

        var allSids = _gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName,
            "Project Collection Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);

        listAllUsers.ItemsSource = _gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, allSids.Members,
            QueryMembership.None).Where(a => a.Type == IdentityType.WindowsUser
                || a.Type == IdentityType.WindowsGroup);

        listProjects.ItemsSource = _css.ListAllProjects();
    }
```

I can't do it when implement this function on asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement your own Project Picker or supply the project collection uri directly to the `TfsTeamProjectCollectionfactory.GetProjectCollection` method. See [the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsteamprojectcollectionfactory.aspx).

To create your own Project Picker, you can use the  `TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer` to connect to a TFS instance. See [the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconfigurationserverfactory_methods.aspx). Then you can query all the Team Project Collections and the underlying Team Projects from there. [See the following piece of documentation for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx).